# Passando o texto dos campos em JS

Tags: javascript, html

Bem, eu passo os dados dos meus campos via **JS** (os códigos deles)!

Exemplo no **JS**:

```
function f_veri_dados()
{
    w_form="sai_frm_incl_novo_cara_peri1";
    // Periferico do programa anterior
    w_param = document.forms[w_form].w_cb_peri.value+"@";
    // Marca 
    if(document.forms[w_form].nm_cb_fk_seq_marc.value == "0")
      {     
      alert("Informe a Marca!!");
      document.forms[w_form].nm_cb_fk_seq_marc.focus();
      return false;
      }   
    w_param = w_param + document.forms[w_form].nm_cb_fk_seq_marc.value+"@";  
    // Modelo
    w_param = document.forms[w_form].nm_cb_fk_seq_mode.value+"@";  
    // Nota fiscal
    if(document.forms[w_form].nm_cb_nota_fisc.value == "0")
      {     
      alert("Informe a Nota Fiscal!!");
      document.forms[w_form].nm_cb_nota_fisc.focus();
      return false;
      }     
      w_param = w_param + document.forms[w_form].nm_cb_nota_fisc.value+"@"
}
```

Dentro do `HTML` eu chamo a `function f_veri_dados()` para pegar os dados dos campos! Mas, eu gostaria de passar também o texto que o usuário "digitou".

**HTML:**

```
<table border="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="hidden" name="w_cb_peri" value="<?=$w_cb_peri;?>">
        </td>               
        <td align="right" colspan="3" width="12%">
            <font face="arial" color="blue" size="2">Marca :</font>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?
                $w_querybusca="select * from sai_tb_marc order by desc_marc;";
                $w_queryresultado=f_class_conecta_bd($w_querybusca);
                if (pg_num_rows($w_queryresultado) == 0)
                {
                    print("<SCRIPT language=javascript> alert(\"Cadastre uma marca.\");
                        parent.location.replace(\"../sai_prin/sai_menu0.php\");</SCRIPT>");
                }
                print('<select name="nm_cb_fk_seq_marc" id="id_cb_fk_seq_marc" onchange="f_le_modelo(this.form.name);" style="font-size:11; color:Black; width:120">'."\n");
                print('<option value="0"> Selecione</option>'."\n");
                while($w_registro = pg_fetch_object($w_queryresultado))
                {
                    print('<option value="'.$w_registro->seq_marc.'">'.trim($w_registro->desc_marc).'</option>'."\n");
                }
                print ("</select>");
           ?>           
        </td>
        <td align="right" width="14%" >
            <font face="arial" color="blue" size="2">Modelo :</font>
        </td>
        <td id="td_fk_seq_mode" colspan="3" width="20%">
            <select name="nm_cb_fk_seq_mode" id="id_cb_fk_seq_mode" style="font-size:11; color:Black;" width="90">
                <option id="opc_fk_seq_mode" value="0"> Selecione
                </option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td align="right" width="29%">
            <font face="arial" color="blue" size="-1">Nota Fiscal :</font>
        </td>
        <td align="left" width="17%">
            <?
                $w_querybusca="select * from sai_cad_nf order by num_nf;";
                $w_queryresultado=f_class_conecta_bd($w_querybusca);
                print('<select name="nm_cb_nota_fisc" style="font-size:11; color:Black; width:100">'."\n");
                print('<option value="0"> Selecione</option>'."\n");
                while($w_registro = pg_fetch_object($w_queryresultado))
                {
                    print('<option value="'.$w_registro->seq_nf.'">'.trim($w_registro->num_nf).'</option>'."\n");
                }
                print ("</select>");
            ?>  
        </td>   
    </tr>   
</table><br>
<table border="0" width="50%" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td width="50%">
            <button type="button" style="width:65"  onclick="f_veri_dados();"><img src="../sai_imag/novo-reg.ico">
            </button>
        </td>               
    </tr>
</table>
```

Deixe-me explicar melhor ... Eu quero passar o texto de uma `combo`. Ou seja, nessa maneira que estou fazendo ele só pega o código da opção (na `combo`) selecionada e eu gostaria de passar o texto (nome) dela junto!

Comment: Tem de mostrar o seu HTML para ser mais claro o problema

Comment: HTML posto!!!!!

Comment: @Bruno, se está solucionado, por favor, aceite a resposta que solucionou o seu problema ou crie você mesmo a resposta para que no futuro esse post ajude outra pessoa.

Answer (score 2):

Tecnicamente isso deveria ser um comentário, mas existem tantos pontos a serem considerados que é preferível redigir com mais cuidado.

Sua pergunta está bastante confusa, mas aparentemente bastaria, dentro da função:

```
var campoDesejado = document.getElementById('campoDesejado').value;
```

Sendo **campoDesejado** o atributo ID de um `<input>`:

```
<input type="text" id="campoDesejado" />
```

Mas eu sugeriria que você se organizasse melhor:

1. Até mesmo por questões de segurança, evite usar os nomes das colunas do seu banco de dados diretamente no HTML. Isso abre a possibilidade de um possível invasor conhecer o básico da sua estrutura sem nem tentar invadir seu banco.
2. Elementos de formulário devem estar dentro de `<form>`. Se já estão, pelo código apresentado você teria apenas um então dispare a função no Evento [onSubmit()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_form_onsubmit.asp) e, das uma, ou informe à função o identificador do formulário ou defina-o dentro da própria função de forma mais clara do que tem hoje:

   ```
   function  myFunction( form ) {

       // form.action reporta myAction.php
   }
   ```

Ou, alternativamente:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function  myFunction() {

        var w_form = document.forms[ 'sai_frm_incl_novo_cara_peri1' ]

        // E a partir daí você só usa a variável w_forms
    }

</script>
```

Se, porventura, você tiver múltiplos formulário na mesma tela (oq ue por si só já não é o ideal) ao invés de trabalhar com a coleção de formulários (document.forms), trabalhe com classes.

1. Se tudo isso for suficiente, mas houver necessidade de melhorar ainda mais, refatore seu código e separe o HTML do JavaScript.

É quase a mesma coisa, mas ao invés de usar o Evento [onSubmit](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_form_onsubmit.asp) diretamente no HTML, você varia no JS:

```
window.onload = function() {

    var form = document.getElementById( 'form' );

    if( form.addEventListener ) {

        form.addEventListener(

            'submit', mySubmitFunction, false
        );

    } else if( form.attachEvent ) {

        form.attachEvent( 'onsubmit', mySubmitFunction );
    }
};

function mySubmitFunction( event ) {

    alert( this.action );

    event.preventDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Obrigado pela ajuda @BrunoAugusto!

Mas encontrei uma maneira mais "eficiente" de mostrar o nome!

```
var marca = document.getElementById("id_cb_fk_seq_marc").options[document.getElementById("id_cb_fk_seq_marc").selectedIndex].text;
alert(marca);
```

Comment: Que bom que solucionou sozinho, mas veja como em fazendo a pergunta certa a resposta teria vindo mais rápido: "Como fazer para, nessa função, obter o texto da opção selecionada em um menu dropdown?". ;)